# How $f$ depends of $y$?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

$\bf{Definition:}$ We say that $f$ not depends of $i$-th variable if $x, x + te_{i} \in U \Longrightarrow f(x) = f(x + te_{i})$.

> Let $X = \lbrace (x,0)\;|\;x \geq0\rbrace$ and $U = \mathbb{R}^{2} - X$. Define $f:U \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x,y) = x^{2}$ if $x > 0, y>0$ and $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x \leq 0$. Show that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 0$ for all $u \in U$ but $f$ depends of $y$.

$\it{Partial\; solution}$ (Attemp). If $x_{1}>0, y_{1}>0$

$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{1},y_{1}) = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_{1}, y_{1} + ty) - f(x_{1},y_{1})}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{x_{1}^{2} - x_{1}^{2}}{t} = 0$$

and if $x_{1} \leq 0$
$$\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(x_{1}, y_{1} + ty) - f(x_{1},y_{1})}{t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{0 - 0}{t} = 0.$$

But, and $y<0$? The function is defined? Moreover, I don't see how $f$ depends of $y$, because only $x$ determines de value of the function (intuitively). Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

The domain $U\ne\Bbb R^2$. *First*, $f$ isn't defined when $x\ge 0$ and $y = 0$. In particular, $f(0,0)$ isn't defined... but *after* is defined when you say $f(x,y) = 0$ if $x\ge 0$.

Another problem: You don't define $f$ for all the points of $U$. Namely, for $x^2 > 0$, $y < 0$ .

Check again.

Comment: Why? The set $X$ removed only the points $(x, y)$ with $x \geq 0$ and $y = 0$.

Comment: @LucasCorrêa, edited.

Comment: Yes! But, I don't understanding how $f$ depends of $y$. For example, let $a, a + ty$ where $a = (x_{1},y_{1})$ (suppose $x_{1} > 0$), so $f(x_{1},y_{1}) =  x_{1}^{2} = f(x_{1}, y_{1} + ty)$.

Comment: Another problem, the points $(x,y)$ with $x > 0$ and $y<0$ don't seem defined for me

Comment: @LucasCorrêa, if you have correctly transcribed the problem, the statement is wrong.